# Not sure how to pull the the value of a second select statement in SqlCommand C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to pull a value from the second select statement in the `SqlCommand` that sums the total points possible and awarded from the first table. I was using the TOTALPOSSIBLE_SUM variable to try and pull the 5th element but it threw an exception.

Any ideas on how I would go about grabbing those 2 SUM values? Thanks

```
        const int COL_NAME = 1;
        const int COL_DUE_DATE = 2;
        const int COL_POINTS_POSSIBLE = 3;
        const int COL_POINTS_AWARDED = 4;
        const int TOTALPOSSIBLE_SUM = 5;
        const int TOTALAWARDED_SUM = 6;


        // SQL statement to select the columns from the table
        command.CommandText =
            "SELECT * FROM " +
            "[dbo].[Assignments_Table] ORDER BY [PkID] DESC;" +
            "SELECT SUM(PointsPossible), SUM(PointsAwarded) " +
            "FROM [dbo].[Assignments_Table]";

        assignments_view.Items.Clear();

        // SQL reader to read the data from the database into the list view
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Assignment newAssignment = new Assignment();
                    ListViewItem assignmentItem = new ListViewItem();
                    // ID
                    newAssignment.ID = reader.GetInt32(COL_PKID);
                    // Name
                    newAssignment.Name = reader.GetString(COL_NAME);
                    // Due Date
                    newAssignment.DueDate = reader.GetDateTime(COL_DUE_DATE); 
                    // Possible Points
                    newAssignment.PointsPossible = reader.GetInt32(COL_POINTS_POSSIBLE);
                    // Awarded Points
                    newAssignment.PointsAwarded = reader.GetInt32(COL_POINTS_AWARDED);

                    newAssignment.TotalPointsPossible = reader.GetInt32(TOTALPOSSIBLE_SUM);
                    newAssignment.TotalPointsAwarded = reader.GetInt32(TOTALAWARDED_SUM);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read the results of a batch **SQL** statement, you can use the [`NextResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult(v=vs.110).aspx) method to position the `DataReader` at the next result in the resultset.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    //Write logic to process data for the first result.     
}


reader.NextResult(); // next resultset

while (reader.Read())
{
    //Write logic to process data for the second result.
}
```

`NextResult` returns *true* if there are more result sets; otherwise *false*, so I would suggesting using this.

```
if(reader.NextResult()) // next resultset
{
     while (reader.Read())
     {
          //Write logic to process data for the second result.
     }
}
```